# Apply a jQuery function to different elements to set dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I'm using a jQuery and CSS to set width and height to grid columns and its inside elements.

The function is working fine when I apply to grid container with 2 columns ( [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FUn58/1/) ) or grid with 3 columns ( [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/FUn58/2/) ) separately but when I try to combine both the script get the block width from the last loaded element which is the 3 columns grid elements like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/FUn58/)

Here is my code:

## HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="grid-2cols full-img">
      <div class="col">
         <a class="full-block" href="">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <a class="full-block" href="">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-3cols full-img">
      <div class="col">
         <a class="full-block" href="">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <a class="full-block" href="">
         </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <a class="full-block" href="">
         </a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.container {width:80%; margin:0 auto;}
.grid-2cols,
.grid-3cols {
    width:100%
}
.col {
    float:left; padding:1%; border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}
.grid-2cols .col {
    width:43%; margin:2%;
}
.grid-3cols .col {
    width:27%; margin:2%;
}
.full-block {background:#000; display:block;}
```

## jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img_width, img_height, img_gap;
    $(".grid-2cols.full-img").each(function () {
        var e = $('.grid-2cols').find(".col").width();
        $(".full-block").each(function () {
            MakeOverlay(e);
        });
    });
    $(".grid-3cols.full-img").each(function () {
        var x = $('.grid-3cols').find(".col").width();
        $(".full-block").each(function () {
            MakeOverlay(x);
        });

    });
    function MakeOverlay(e) {
        $(".full-block").each(function () {
            img_width = (Math.floor(e));
            img_height = (img_width * 0.56);
            img_gap = (img_width * 0.56 * 0.62);
            $(this).css({ 'height': img_height, 'width': img_width });
        });
    };

});
```

## Screenshot

Here is what I'm trying to achieve 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting `.full-block` one by one and pass them to `MakeOverlay()`

```
fullBlockEl = $(this).find('.full-block');
MakeOverlay(x, fullBlockEl);
```